# Graph search for element by element's name in jointJS

Tags: search, graph, jointjs, rappid

I have a problem in Rappid/jointJS

I have in stencil.js 4 shapes(2 basic.Circle and 2 basic.Rect) with names START(basic.Circle), END(basic.Circle), Activity(basic.Rect) and Workitem( basic.Rect)  and **I want** in my main.js **from all my graph to get the basic shape with name(I mean with attrs text ) "Activity".**

This is the Stencil description for "Activity" :

```
new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({ size: { width: 5, height: 3 },
attrs: {
    rect: {
         rx: 2, ry: 2, width: 50, height: 30,
         fill: '#0000FF'
       },
       text: { text: 'Activity', fill: '#ffffff', 'font-size': 10, 
       stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-width': 0 }
     }
}),
```

How wil I get it? The only way I can search in my graph so far is if a cell has type basic.Circle(use of `get('type') === 'basic.Circle')`). but with type Circle I have two items:Activity and Workitem.

Is it so difficult to search for the graph element with name : "Activity"?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by name? Did you specify it as an attribute property of the model?

Comment: Yes @SajithDilshan I have the attribute "text". can you help me access Activity? This is the Stencil description for "Activity" : new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
            size: { width: 5, height: 3 },
            attrs: {
                rect: {
                    rx: 2, ry: 2, width: 50, height: 30,
                    fill: '#0000FF'
                },
                text: { text: 'Activity', fill: '#ffffff', 'font-size': 10, stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-width': 0 }
            }
        }),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by taking element data in JSON format:

```
 _.each(this.graph.getElements(), function(element) {


             if(element.attributes.attrs["text"]["text"] == "Activity"){
             //alert("YEAHHHHHH");
             }

            });
```

Comment: JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() lines are redundant. the 'element' variable is already a Javascript object.

Comment: Thank you @SajithDilshan but if(element.attrs["text"]["text"] == "Activity"){
             //alert("YEAHHHHHH");

             } 
doesn't work in my case. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: It should be if(element.attributes.attrs["text"]["text"] == "Activity").
Further, you can inspect the full structure of element object by executing console.log(element) and this will print the object into browser console.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain all the elements (except for links) from following method

```
var allElement = graph.getElements()
```

Next if you want to obtain elements with 'Activity' do as follows

```
var activityElements = [];

allElement.forEach(elem => {
    var textVal = elem.attributes.attrs.text.text;
    if(textVal !== undefined && textVal === 'Activity') {
        activityElements.push(elem);
    }
});
```

Now the activityElements array will contain all the elements you require.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the api on element as well, `element.attr('text')` returns the `text` object from the shape: `{ text: 'Activity', fill: '#ffffff', 'font-size': 10, 
       stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-width': 0 }`

Answer (score 0):

You could also set an "id" attribute to your shape and use `graph.getCell('id_name_goes_here');` which would be much simpler if you didn't mind adding an id field to each shape.